# Transferring M4V/MP4 files into iTunes

Tags: itunes, mp4

I'm moving my iTunes library to another computer that already had iTunes on it (both are Windows-based). On the original computer, video files loaded and played fine (I sync to an Apple TV). I tried to import video files that worked just fine on the original into the new one and they don't come over.  If I copy the files into iTunes on a Mac, they work.

This ISN'T an encoding issue (I believe) as the files work properly on other iTunes. The only difference is one machine is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you are saying the iTunes on 64 bit version does not work with itunes 32 bit.

Comment: What versions of itunes do you have on both sides?

Comment: did you check this out http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1784

Comment: Buscar - THANK YOU - that solved the problem entirely!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscar found the solution (noted in the comments):

Apple had released a v12.1.1 for 64-bit machines that allowed earlier encoded videos to be imported properly.

The URL is http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1784

Busker thank you!